# Trouble installing a package with chocolatey: System.Management.Automation.RemoteException

Tags: installation, chocolatey, poweshell

I'm trying to install a package with chocolatey 2.2.2 (the package is texlive), using a PowerShell session run as administrator.

I get the following error:

```
-- snip ---
texlive package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
Additional parameters for installer:
Writing Profile
Writing Profile using Passed Parameters.
TeX Live Profile will be written to C:\tools\texlive.profile
Extracting C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\texlive\tools\install-tl.zip to C:\tools\install-tl-29102315...
C:\tools\install-tl-29102315
Automated TeX Live installation using profile: C:/tools/texlive.profile
Loading https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
ERROR: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: System.Management.Automation.RemoteException
The install of texlive was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\texlive\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
```

why am I getting this error? Can I change this "preference variable" to circumvent it?

Comment: Don’t let the message confuse you. It does not contain any relevant details, those will be in the log file. Do check it! // Also, no, you generally must not allow a script to continue on errors. This could have catastrophic results.

Comment: [ErrorActionPreference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.3#erroractionpreference) is a PowerShell variable specifying how to treat errors, which is in your case set to Stop, and which should stay this way. You could try to specify a larger timeout for chocolatey, see [link](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/configuration#timeouts). Or just use a texlive installation not through chocolatey.